# jquery-ui dialog doesn't open immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a simple display of progress for the user while actions are happening. While doing this I noticed jquery-ui dialog didn't open until all javascript had finished.

I have created some pseudo code but the example shows the issue:
Working example: http://jsbin.com/isivus

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HoL</title>
</head>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false
        });

        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: 0
        });

        $('input').click(function() {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                var span = document.getElementById('span');
                $('span').text(i);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
        <div id="dialog">
            <span class="dialogText">text</span>
            <div id="progressbar"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Click me!" />
        <span id="span"></span>
</body>
```

The dialog doesn't open until the loop has finished. Seeing as I want to show the dialog, and update the text while the loop is running this isn't really working.

I am no javascript expert and have no clue where the issue is coming from, hoping any of you could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will block everything (most likely **the whole browser**) while it's running.

Split it into small chunks of maybe 10 or 100 loops and then continue asynchronously (i.e. with a zero-delay setTimeout).

Here's some code that might do the job:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    var i = 0, elem = $('#span');
    function loop() {
        for(var end = i + 100; i < end; i++) {
            elem.text(i);
        }
        if(i < 100000) {
            window.setTimeout(loop, 0);
        }
    }
    loop();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/fKqQg/3/

Comment: Heh! My reaction to that demo: Awesome! Ill fiddle with it to fit my code, I see the issue now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Move the `for` loop inside a standalone function, and use the dialogs `open` event to call it.

```
  $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        open: myBlockingLoopFunction, 
        closeOnEscape: false
    });

 function myBlockingFunction() { 
      // your loop here
 }
```

Comment: That still blocks the browser during the loop.